# Chrome automatically download local file

Tags: google-chrome, markdown

I want to view the markdown file in my Chrome browser; however when I open the local `markdown file` it download the file in my local directory. However, I tried with `TXT` file and browser address location looks - `file:///C:/` that works fine though. The same approach like `TXT file` does not work for `markdown file`.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciate. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Chrome will not support the all content type it will support only some specified content type. If you want to show the file into your browser you need to set the headers.

Here is the GITHUB Block how they show all files

> https://github.com/blog/1482-heads-up-nosniff-header-support-coming-to-chrome-and-firefox

Comment: I added following line in the header of the markdown file, but does not work 
<meta content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8; X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
Any suggestion ?